# "ginvalidate frame buffer" calls when testing Unity VR app on Renderdoc

Tags: unity, frame-rate

[image]

Hi I'm testing out a VR app created in unity 2020 LTR and I'm currently hitting 71fps.. Render doc shows atleast 6ms.. being taken up by the givalidate frame buffer call, happening twice..

What is this?.. and how do I speed things up.. Already done all the optimisations, all I have in the scene is 1 piece of geometry, and a skymap..

Any help is appreciated..

Screenshot is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SwmQFCIKhJlvToJct9fMbJC3OUt7Syz-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The link to your image gives me an `access denied` error; please use the built in Stack Exchange tools for posting images whenever possible. You can find help on how to do so [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/228147).

Comment: Picture added thanks, any advice would be great..